# Random variable is parameter for distribution of another random variable

Tags: probability, self-study, random-variable, uniform-distribution

What would you do to find probability when a uniform random variable is the parameter for the distribution of another uniform random variable.

ie:
$Z \sim Unif(0,1)$
$Y \sim Unif(0,Z)$

And we are interested in finding the probability of $Y$ either $>, <$, or $=$.

I feel as if I have to use a double integral but am not sure where to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

Use conditional probability, first figure out $P(Y \le y|Z=z)$ and $f_Z(z)$

Now you can compute the following:

\begin{align}
P(Y \le y) &= \int_y^1 P(Y \le y|Z=z)f_Z(z)\, dz
\end{align}

Comment: Could you complete the computation?  I think I'm making a mistake in my own calculations and would like to verify the result of the integral.

Comment: I was hoping that the OP would post his working after following the guide. Any particular step/term that you are uncertain?

Comment: The result of the integral diverges, leading me to believe the marginal of $y$ may not exist.

Comment: I made a mistake earlier, $z$ can only take values that are larger than $y$. Thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Comment: I am having a lot of trouble coming up with what would (≤|=) be since Y and Z are dependent random variables. I know that () = 1 but am not sure what to do

Comment: We have $P(Y \le y|Z=z) = \frac{y}{z}$ since it is $\operatorname{Uni}(0,z)$.

Comment: And when I put y/z into the integral I can replace y with whatever value is in the initial probability statement (≤|=), correct?

Comment: For example if i was trying to find P(Y <= 0.6) I would put (≤|=) = 0.6/z

Comment: yes, that is correct.